# Davidson-MacKinnon J test vs Cox test for comparing two non-nested models

Tags: r, nested-models

In library "lmtest" The jtest and coxtest functions are used to see if two non-nested models are equivalent.

According to the help function:

```
jtest performs the Davidson-MacKinnon J test for comparing non-nested models. 

coxtest performs the Cox test for comparing two non-nested models.
```

Under what conditions should one be used over the other?